# Number section-LaTex

Tags: formatting, sections-paragraphs, random-numbers

How Can I change the format number section, subsection, and subsubsection? 
The document put:

Section (I.)
Subsection (I.1)
Subsubsection (I.1.1)

But... I want:

Section (I.)
Subsection (1.1)
Subsubsection (1.1.1)

How do I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What you want is the default for all standard classes. So there is something in your document, which changes the default behaviour.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}`?

Comment: The sequence `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}` *should* work in your document class but you'd be *way* better off if you provided us with an explicit example.

Comment: Schrödinger's cat-- Thank you! I  could already!, With the first comment

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat -- If an answer would be useful, please add one; otherwise, nominate for closure.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat -- The OP in a comment says that the problem is solved "with the first comment."  Unfortunately, I.m not in a position to experiment, so can't say whether it's an actual solution, or just a good enough pointer in the right direction.  Which is why I turned it back to you.  In its present state, it's not super helpful ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton You win. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The old-fashioned approach to change the numbering scheme is

```
\renewcommand{\the<counter>}{<representation>{<counter>}}
```

e.g.

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

Promoted to a complete minimal working example this leads to

```
\documentclass{article} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, this does not require any package. On the one hand, this is good. On the other hand, this also means that this may not necessarily yield the desired results in connection with arbitrary document class and packages. More advanced ways to change the section numbering may be based on the `titlesec` and also `titletoc` packages, yet this answer only spells out the old-fashioned method.